# Sonicwall with BGP unable to route to AWS VPN

Tags: vpn, bgp, firewall, sonicwall

I'm trying to get our local [Sonicwall NSA 2600 to connect to a AWS VPN, within a VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide/sonicwall-bgp.html). I have the IKE portion working and AWS shows the two pipes are connected

[image]

The BGP routes show as up in the router

```
(config-routing)# show routing bgp summary
BGP router identifier 192.168.1.3, local AS number 65000
BGP table version is 8737
2 BGP AS-PATH entries
0 BGP community entries

Neighbor        V    AS MsgRcvd MsgSent   TblVer  InQ OutQ Up/Down  State/PfxRcd
169.254.45.245  4  7224   51909   63298     8736    0    0 5d20h55m        1
169.254.46.161  4  7224   52390   63791     8736    0    0 5d20h55m        1

Total number of neighbors 2
```

What's baffling is that it appears that everything appears to be there. But attempting to get anything to route to the 174.0.0.0/16 block doesn't work (I know it's a public block but I can't change it at present)

```
(config-routing)# show routing nsm database

C    *> 169.254.45.244/30 is directly connected, T2
C    *> 169.254.45.247/32 is directly connected, T2
C    *> 169.254.46.160/30 is directly connected, T1
C    *> 169.254.46.163/32 is directly connected, T1
B    *> 174.0.0.0/16 [20/100] via 169.254.46.161, T1, 5d20h57m
C    *> 192.168.1.0/24 is directly connected, X0
```

I've never dealt with BGP so I'm at a complete loss how to debug it further, or determine how to get it to send into or out of the VPC. I cannot get pings, RDC or SSH to work through the internal IPs.

Adding the route table, as obtained from my PC

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.3    192.168.1.153    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.153    281
    192.168.1.153  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.153    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.153    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.153    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.153    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.3  Default
===========================================================================
```

There is a route in the Sonicwall routing

[image]

I played with this some and got the BGP routes listed correctly, but still no luck on getting traffic to flow

```
   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
*  174.0.0.0        169.254.45.245         200             0 7224 i
*>                  169.254.46.161         100             0 7224 i
*> 192.168.1.0      0.0.0.0                       100  32768 i
```

Comment: Are you using those link-local addresses based on the tutorial or from your actual configuration? I've never used AWS but that seems strange. Can you ping the BGP neighbors?

Comment: what is your route for 169.254.46.161 in the routing table?

Comment: I cannot ping the BGP neighbors. The addressing was provided directly by AWS itself

Comment: @john On the AWS side or the Sonicwall?

Comment: Please show the route table from both sides.

Comment: I've added some more routing info

Comment: It's hard to help you if you just keep spoon-feeding us information.  Please post your router configs and the routing table from *both sides*.   From what you've posted so far, I don't see a route from the VPC back to you.

Comment: @RonTrunk I promise I'm not trying to spoon feed anything. I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for beyond what I've added. Is there a command I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: Please post your router configuration

Comment: I dont see a route for 169.254.46.161 in the table.

Comment: Can you only ping with the VPN working? If not, I would like to confirm indeed that you are able to reach that destination (ping/traceroute), else disregard test.

Comment: @DRP I've tried pinging the routes themselves and gotten nowhere. Traceroute has gone nowhere as well

Comment: @Machavity Ping tested hop by hop or how far? Any tcpdump taken? What do the net stats say?The last img is from the Amazon VPC console? Can you feed a /32 address from the 174 block to not rely on summary?

Comment: @DRP I've tried to traceroute but I get `*` for each hop and it runs all 30 hops. Not familiar with tcpdump so no. Sonicwall doesn't have a netstat that I can tell (CLI or otherwise). Edited to clarify the image is from the Sonicwall routing page. The Sonicwall has locked the 174 block so I haven't been able to try going from the /16 block to a smaller one

Comment: Pretty sure there has to be a netstat command, this [link] (http://help.sonicwall.com/help/sw/eng/published/1344639274_3.1.0/Appendix_A_CLI_Guide/CLIguide.htm) has a cli example, although not sure if it works for your Sonic version. The idea is to try to narrow down more the issue by gathering additional facts (data). Regarding tcpdump this is just a capture of what is occurring down the wire as you used i.e wireshark, although this should be last resource. BTW are you selecting what IP is sourced when running the PING? Anything new you would like to add?

Comment: @DRP `show netstat` doesn't work. Tried several different ways but it's not listed as a command for `show`. Maybe that's for a different version of SonicOS (am using 6.2.6.1). Have not tried anything beyond a normal ping

Comment: @Machavity Are there any logs available to check out? This guide has a way to set them up>> http://software.sonicwall.com/Manual/232-001835-00_Rev_A_SonicOS_Log_Event_Reference_Guide.pdf

Comment: @Machavity did you ever get this solved?

Comment: @DRP I would up paying someone more familiar with BGP to get it going. Can't say I understand everything he did or I would have posted an answer

Comment: One observation is that to have BGP neighbors, they must have configured fixed addresses, and it violates the RFC to statically configure, subnet, route, etc for the `169.254.0.0/16` network. You seem to have statically configured those addresses, and you are subnetting them, both of which are not allowed by the standard. It looks like you may also have configured loopbacks in that range, and those must be routed, which is also not allowed.

Comment: NetRange:       169.254.0.0 - 169.254.255.255
CIDR:           169.254.0.0/16
NetName:        LINKLOCAL-RFC3927-IANA-RESERVED This is a reserved range for link-local. Wondering how the BGP Neighbors are working and if these are the right BGP neighbors. Change This IP Block to a RFC1918, but do not use a LINKLOCAL reserved IP pool for this.